# How to swap ground and power for multimeter

Tags: arduino-nano

I'm trying to create a multimeter that measures resistance and capacitance for a school project and the code must be under 30 lines. I have made both a resistance meter and a capacitance meter but the only problem is that on for my resistance meter, ground is connected to the to the known resistor and the arduino's output goes through the unknown component. Where as my capacitance meter is the opposite (ground to unknown, output to known), just wondering if their is an easy fix or if i need to rethink my entire project. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You could use an H-bridge to reverse the polarity

Comment: Please show your schematic. It is unclear what you mean.

Comment: Arduino have a lot of pins, can you use one pin for resistance and other for capacitance?